# laravel 5.7 API Authentication (Passport) Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am trying to authenticate api calls in my laravel 5.7 application. I have installed Passport following the documentation and I think I have not missed anything. Every API call returns a 401 Unauthenticated.

Debugging I have found that the problem is that the csrf token encrypted in a cookie (once it is decrypted) doesn't match the csrf header from the request. I know it because I am dumping `$this->validCsrf($token, $request)` inside the `getTokenViaCookie($request)` method in [vendor/laravel/passport/src/Guards/TokenGuard.php](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7.0/src/Guards/TokenGuard.php#L224) and it's value is false.

I cannot think what I am doing wrong.

In my `layout.blade.php` I add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

In `Kernel.php` I add `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class` after `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class`

And in telescope I can see in the request that the `x-xsrf-token` header and the `laravel_token` cookie are there.

Any idea about what the problem can be or any way to debug it will be welcome.

---

I have done a deeper look into the code, I see that the token encrypted and saved into the cookie [seems to be the session token](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7.0/src/Http/Middleware/CreateFreshApiToken.php#L54). In passport/src/Http/Middleware/CreateFreshApiToken.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $this->guard = $guard;
        $response = $next($request);
        if ($this->shouldReceiveFreshToken($request, $response)) {
            $response->withCookie($this->cookieFactory->make(
                $request->user($this->guard)->getKey(), $request->session()->token()
            ));
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

So it looks like my problem is that the token encrypted is the session one then it gets compared with the csrf header and of course the authentication fails.

I wondr if this is the normal behaviour and I am missing something Or is it wrong?

Comment: What error you're exactly getting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307909/laravel-passport-auth-through-createfreshapitoken-always-returns-messageuna/54310098#54310098

Comment: Tamilvanan N, Laravel is replying with a  "401 Unauthorized"

Comment: Alexandre, I have tried your solution in that link and it doesn't make any difference. But thanks :)

Comment: I have edited the question with some more info

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was.

Because I am using bootstrap-vue I stopped using bootstrap. What I didn't realized is that in [the vue app](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/app.js#L8) when it requires `./bootstrap.js` it is not only loading bootstrap, it is also setting some headers.